# Phalcon: How to save array ($model->create())

Tags: php, phalcon

$model->create() no save array

```
$User= new \User();
$User->id = 1;
$User->data = [0=>123456789];
$User->create();`
```

$model->update() success save array

```
$User= \User::findFirst(1);
$User->data = [0=>123456789];
$User->update();
```

I save array $model->create()

```
class User extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->setConnectionService('db_id');
        $this->useDynamicUpdate(true);
    }

    public function beforeSave()
    {
        $this->data = serialize($this->data);
    }

    public function afterFetch()
    {
        $this->data = unserialize($this->data);
    }
}
```

phalcon version 1.3.2

Comment: Try to use `beforeCreate()` in your model

Comment: Thanks, but not work

Comment: $model->create() no save array. bug?

Comment: Have you set all fields that are not allowed to be NULL?

Comment: what type is your data column of db table user?